# ORACLE Client sqlplus of version 10.2.0.1 is not able to connect to upgraded ORACLE 12.2.0.1

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I checked the solution in internet, but the below does not helps.

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=8
```

First I got the error from sqlplus client:

> ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol

So the above configuration resolved the issue.
But now I am getting this error from the client.

> ERROR: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Comment: Common, I have already checked from the DB side, login is working fine, that I know why this error is , I have already retried to reset the password to the same which client uses, but still there is error, hence I have posted this query. or else I would have myself fixed this issue. hence please let me know if somebody knows the error.

Comment: Your question doesn't say you've verified anything. The error is that you have invalid credentials. Maybe you aren't connecting to quite what you think - a different database, or just a different PDB to the one you checked against. How did you check they were correct - which client, and connecting how? It might be useful to show the working and non-working connection strings, and TNS entries if relevant, to see if that highlights the mistake.

Comment: You could also download the 12.2 or later [instant client](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/overview/index.html) and see what happens when you use that connect with exactly the same credentials and connection string.

Comment: Thank you , but we cannot upgrade the version of the client, let me download the oracle 12.2.0.4 client and check the same issue, I will update If I can connect using the 10.2.0.4 client version, I suspect an issue with version 10.2.0.1, anyway thank you for responding to my issue, much appreciated for your support.

Comment: Additionally the user having logging problem since after upgrading the DB the problem is only with the users having password version as 11G 12C. so if any knowhow for this issue

Comment: Ah, OK, then I take my my earlier scepticism *8-) [This may be helpful](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/upgrd/case-insensitive-passwords-ora-1017-invalid-username-password.html#GUID-FDA9C77A-12F4-4410-9448-9BCC13960C27). You need to change the password again after changing the `sqlnet.ora` parameter, I think?

Answer (score 2):

hi as I said in the previous issue, the PASSWORD VERSION was seen as 11G 12C, so I again resetted my password again to the same as used by the client.
the password version is now changed to 10G 11G 12C and hence now works from 10g client.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check the [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 207303.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1)

[image]

Officially it is not possible to connect to an Oracle 12.2.0 database with an 10.2.0 client. You should really consider an upgrade of your client. Perhaps you will face other issues which are not as easy to solve like changing the password.